# Getting Facebook Reactions with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook just released the new reaction button, but I can't figure out a way to get this information from the Graph API v2.5 as the /likes edge only returns the total count of interactions.

Has anyone figured out a way to get this detailed reactions per post?

Comment: There is no way as of now, reactions are being rolled out today. It will most likely come to the API soon.

Comment: There is no official word from facebook when these will be available, but I am sure they will either remove the reactions altogether or provide an edge to get the data.

Comment: just wait for it to pop up in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: As of April 12th, 2016 Facebook has published a reactions endpoint for posts as part of their v2.6 release of the GraphAPI

GET /v2.6/{object-id}/reactions

More information can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/reactions

END EDIT

I'm not sure if Facebook has published this yet, but the reaction information is currently available in the Graph API v2.5. I pasted the response below. I achieved this result by hitting the insights endpoint. For each object listed in the response below, take a look at the 'id' property, it has more granular query endpoints.

```
GET /v2.5/{object-id}/insights
```

RESPONSE:

```
   {
  "name": "post_reactions_like_total",
  "period": "lifetime",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": 0
    }
  ],
  "title": "Lifetime Like Reactions",
  "description": "Lifetime: The total number of like reactions to your post.",
  "id": "{node_id}/insights/post_reactions_like_total/lifetime"
},
{
  "name": "post_reactions_love_total",
  "period": "lifetime",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": 0
    }
  ],
  "title": "Lifetime Love Reactions",
  "description": "Lifetime: The total number of love reactions to your post.",
  "id": "{node_id}/insights/post_reactions_love_total/lifetime"
},
{
  "name": "post_reactions_wow_total",
  "period": "lifetime",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": 0
    }
  ],
  "title": "Lifetime Wow Reactions",
  "description": "Lifetime: The total number of wow reactions to your post.",
  "id": "{node_id}/insights/post_reactions_wow_total/lifetime"
},
{
  "name": "post_reactions_haha_total",
  "period": "lifetime",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": 0
    }
  ],
  "title": "Lifetime Haha Reactions",
  "description": "Lifetime: The total number of haha reactions to your post.",
  "id": "{node_id}/insights/post_reactions_haha_total/lifetime"
},
{
  "name": "post_reactions_sorry_total",
  "period": "lifetime",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": 0
    }
  ],
  "title": "Lifetime Sorry Reactions",
  "description": "Lifetime: The total number of sorry reactions to your post.",
  "id": "{node_id}/insights/post_reactions_sorry_total/lifetime"
},
{
  "name": "post_reactions_anger_total",
  "period": "lifetime",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": 0
    }
  ],
  "title": "Lifetime Anger Reactions",
  "description": "Lifetime: The total number of anger reactions to your post.",
  "id": "{node_id}/insights/post_reactions_anger_total/lifetime"
},
{
  "name": "post_reactions_by_type_total",
  "period": "lifetime",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": {
        "like": 0,
        "love": 0,
        "wow": 0,
        "haha": 0,
        "sorry": 0,
        "anger": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "title": "Lifetime Reactions by type",
  "description": "Lifetime: The total number of reactions to your post by type.",
  "id": "{node_id}/insights/post_reactions_by_type_total/lifetime"
}
```

Comment: Was this from a photo of a comment. I can't find it on a photo I'm looking at... and finding it hard to find the ID of one of my comments to double check.

Comment: OK researched a bit more... insights are only available on page/domain/and posts... and posts with only 30 likes or more. src: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights/

Comment: should add a note that the insights API has a pretty long delay and also will double count reactions if someone changes it (if someone first does a love reaction and then changes it to haha, both love and haha will be 1). If you are trying to get realtime results you are better off using the actual reactions API, unfortunately you have to parse the total numbers yourself

Comment: Just for completion, you don't have to count total by yourself in reaction API. Here is example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906590/getting-facebook-post-all-reactions-count-in-single-graph-api-request/37621973

Answer (score 6):

Facebook just released Graph API 2.6 and the reaction endpoint is available like so

```
GET /v2.6/{object-id}/reactions
```

Which returned something like

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "ACCOUNT-ID",
      "name": "ACCOUNT-NAME",
      "type": "HAHA"
    },
    {
      "id": "ACCOUNT-ID",
      "name": "ACCOUNT-NAME",
      "type": "LIKE"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "TkRZAMU9EWTROakF6TmpBM01qYzJPak2TnpnNE5qUTRNRE0zT1RFek16RXkZD",
      "after": "TVRBd01EQTNOekEwTWpnME1EUTJPakUwTazJNVFl4TXc9PQZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

More infos here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/reactions/

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
GET /v2.5/{post_id}/insights/post_reactions_by_type_total
```

Which returns

```
{
 "data": [
  {
     "name": "post_reactions_by_type_total",
     "period": "lifetime",
     "values": [
        {
           "value": {
              "like": 9,
              "love": 0,
              "wow": 1,
              "haha": 0,
              "sorry": 0,
              "anger": 0
           }
        }
     ],
     "title": "Daily total post reactions by type.",
     "description": "Daily total post reactions by type.",
     "id": "{post_id}/insights/post_reactions_by_type_total/lifetime"
   }
 ],
}
```

I have had some luck using the same in Facebook Graph API 2.3, but not for every request

Comment: This will only work if you have a page access token. Other use-cases might not have access to one.

Answer (score 3):

The next version of the GraphAPI (2.6) is due out in March/April timeframe -- so I would expect to see it there.

Answer (score 3):

New reactions picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6kcp.jpg

There aren't any information about this topic so I want to add somethings.

> The next version of the GraphAPI (2.6) is due out in March/April timeframe -- so I would expect to see it there.
>   (Thank you Justin Bowler)

Now at the graph api 2.5 new facebook reactions don't counting.
If you look at post likes you can't see them so we must wait new api version.

Answer (score 3):

The reactions are already available via insights API v2.5. You can get them on post level via `post_reactions_by_type_total` edge and on page level via `page_actions_post_reactions_total` edge.

Comment: Any idea how to call this API for live videos? I mean should I make an app for that or is there any other way like webhook or something, Please tell me how do I get started

Answer (score 1):

The new reaction are not being counted at all right now. the current API is only surfacing the count for the like button, wow, sad, ETC clicks are not being counted in the likes bucket