# Getting Facebook Post all Reactions Count in single Graph API request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As Facebook released the new reaction{NONE, LIKE, LOVE, WOW, HAHA, SAD, ANGRY} feature for post, but I can not figure out to get all reaction counts in single graph API request.

Has anyone figured out a way to get this detailed reactions per post in single request?

Answer (score 44):

The approach introduced by @CBroe appears to be working using [Multiple ID Read Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api).

> ?ids=7175346442_10153799389241443,7175346442_10153799470326443&fields=reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_love),reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_wow),reactions.type(HAHA).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_haha),...

Screenshot from [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/):

[image]

Once a collection of posts is retrieved, one should be able to read reaction counts grouped by type using a single request.  Note, the current limit of ids in the Multiple ID Read Request pattern is 50.

Comment: May I know where is the dot notation documented in Graph API? Thanks!

Comment: But can one unique user... make one total_count increase just by sending many LOVE reactions? I find that those total_count values are unique user's.. If a user sends a LOVE.. the total_count for love increases +1, but if if the same user now sends a ANGRY the total_count for Love decreases and ANGRY augments.

Comment: When i try to use these fields to display FB group/profile feed, I am getting various errors like reactions_haha unknown field. I tried removing that and i see other errors, so i just can't get these reactions counts for group and profile feed. Are there other ways for group and profile?? It works well for FB page only.

Comment: @omarojo users can only have one reaction to a post/comment, you can only change your reaction, not do multiple.

Comment: you may also append `,likes.limit(0).summary(1)` to get the likes along with the reactions

Comment: @rajibBiswas do you know if there is any difference between `likes.summary(1).limit(0)` and `reactions.type(LIKE).summary(total_count).limit(0)`?

Answer (score 15):

Theoretically possible using Field Expansion in combination with [Field Aliases](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/aliasing-fields), like this:

```
?fields=reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(1).as(like),
        reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(1).as(wow),
        reactions.type(SAD).limit(0).summary(1).as(sad),…
```

---

But there still seem to be some bugs in that regard; I frequently got “An unknown error has occurred” while testing this; f.e. replacing the limit value for LIKE with 1 in the above query triggers it …

Comment: That helpful! but it works only with single post ..but as facebook bugs report [unable to use aliasesin page/posts](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/882975555164278/) currently it not supports with page post endpoint.

Answer (score 8):

Simply use the following as part of your graph query

```
fbpageid/posts?fields=created_time,story,message,shares,reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(1).as(like),reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(1).as(love),reactions.type(HAHA).limit(0).summary(1).as(haha),reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(1).as(wow),reactions.type(SAD).limit(0).summary(1).as(sad),reactions.type(ANGRY).limit(0).summary(1).as(angry)&limit=10
```

So I'll be getting Post ID, Created time, Story, Message, Share Count, reaction count (currently 6 reaction) using only 1 query. It works with APi v2.9 as well

Answer (score 7):

If you have `read_insights` permission, you could get reactions in following way for feed or a post

`fields=insights.metric(post_reactions_by_type_total).period(lifetime).as(post_reactions_by_type_total)`

and you would get results like:

```
        "name": "post_reactions_by_type_total",
        "period": "lifetime",
        "values": [
          {
            "value": {
              "like": 10,
              "love": 2,
              "wow": 3,
              "haha": 1,
              "sorry": 1,
              "anger": 2
            }
          }
        ],
```

Comment: i tried this method it works but when i compare the values to the post on facebook it seems that graph api always return to me a higher value of reactions ?!

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to achieve this with 1 request:

```
GET /{userId}?fields=
  posts.as(like){reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(true)},
  posts.as(love){reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(true)},
  posts.as(wow){reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(true)},
  posts.as(haha){reactions.type(HAHA).limit(0).summary(true)},
  posts.as(sad){reactions.type(SAD).limit(0).summary(true)},
  posts.as(angry){reactions.type(ANGRY).limit(0).summary(true)},
  posts.as(thankful){reactions.type(THANKFUL).limit(0).summary(true)}
```

This way you will receive 7 lists of posts (one per each reaction). Example:

```
{
  "like": {
    "data": [<list of posts>]
  },
  "love": {
    "data": [<list of posts>]
  },
  "wow": {
    "data": [<list of posts>]
  },
  "haha": {
    "data": [<list of posts>]
  },
  "sad": {
    "data": [<list of posts>]
  },
  "angry": {
    "data": [<list of posts>]
  },
  "thankful": {
    "data": [<list of posts>]
  },
  "paging": {
    "previous": "...",
    "next": "..."
  },
  "id": "<userId>"
}
```

Comment: on fb graph api explorer, it says: "The posts field does not exist on the PagePost object."