# How can I get Facebook Graph api reaction summary count separately

Tags: facebook-graph-api

[image]

How can I get Facebook Graph api reaction summary count separately,
When I try in Graph Explorer ,
ex: `614689638666135_785960901539007/?fields=reactions.summary(true)`
I get total count and viewer_reaction, but not enough, somebody please help this ?

Comment: I'v tried this and worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906590/getting-facebook-post-all-reactions-count-in-single-graph-api-request

Comment: @JoãoCabral , me too ,same solution

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to specifically ask for each reaction, however as mentioned in the comments, you can leverage Field aliasing.

```
>>> fb_get_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/%s' % result['id']
>>> query_pieces ['reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(true).as(like)','reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(true).as(love)','reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(true).as(wow)','reactions.type(HAHA).limit(0).summary(true).as(haha)','reactions.type(SAD).limit(0).summary(true).as(sad)','reactions.type(ANGRY).limit(0).summary(true).as(angry)', 'reactions.type(THANKFUL).limit(0).summary(true).as(thankful)']
>>> full_query = ",".join(query_pieces)
>>> r = requests.request("GET", fb_get_url, params={'access_token' : my_creds['access_token'], 'fields' : full_query})
>>> print(dumps(r.json(), indent=2))
{
  "love": {
    "data": [], 
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 0, 
      "viewer_reaction": "LIKE"
    }
  }, 
  "like": {
    "data": [], 
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 1, 
      "viewer_reaction": "LIKE"
    }
  }, 
  "wow": {
    "data": [], 
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 1, 
      "viewer_reaction": "LIKE"
    }
  }, 
  "haha": {
    "data": [], 
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 0, 
      "viewer_reaction": "LIKE"
    }
  }, 
  "sad": {
    "data": [], 
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 0, 
      "viewer_reaction": "LIKE"
    }
  }, 
  "thankful": {
    "data": [], 
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 0, 
      "viewer_reaction": "LIKE"
    }
  }, 
  "id": "10100996730306423_10101331756810623", 
  "angry": {
    "data": [], 
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 0, 
      "viewer_reaction": "LIKE"
    }
  }
}
>>>
```

Comment: may I know where is this documented in Graph API ?

Comment: why do you use limit(0) ?

Answer (score 0):

`limit(0)` basically says that you are not interested in individual likes while `summary(true)` gives you the aggregated value (`total_count`)