# HTTP Error 404: Forbidden Error while scraping Facebook group post using graph api

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

So I was working on my academic project that includes scraping Facebook public group posts using python, I have done this more than a couple of times and it worked smoothly. But this time its giving me error:

> HTTP ERROR 404 : Forbidden

I tried scraping Facebook pages and it gave me results smoothly that means the issue is not with Access Token.

I am using the same script that was run successfully previously, tried changing the user access token, app access token, type of request (GET POST) but no success. I am attaching the script that i used (found somewhere at github) also attaching the error logs

```
import urllib.request as ur
import json
import datetime
import csv
import time

group_id = input("Please Paste Public Group ID:")

#access_token = app_id + "|" + app_secret
access_token = input("Please Paste Your Access Token:")
def request_until_succeed(url):
    req = ur.Request(url)
    success = False
    while success is False:
        try: 
            response = ur.urlopen(req)
            if response.getcode() == 200:
                success = True
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            time.sleep(5)

            print ("Error for URL %s: %s" % (url, datetime.datetime.now()))
            print ("Retrying.")

    return response.read()

# Needed to write tricky unicode correctly to csv
def unicode_normalize(text):
    return text.translate({ 0x2018:0x27, 0x2019:0x27, 0x201C:0x22, 0x201D:0x22,
                            0xa0:0x20 }).encode('utf-8')

def getFacebookPageFeedData(group_id, access_token, num_statuses):

    # Construct the URL string; see 
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/37239851 for Reactions parameters
    base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6"
    node = "/%s/feed" % group_id 
    fields = "/?fields=message,link,permalink_url,created_time,type,name,id," + \
            "comments.limit(0).summary(true),shares,reactions." + \
            "limit(0).summary(true),from"
    parameters = "&limit=%s&access_token=%s" % (num_statuses, access_token)
    url = base + node + fields + parameters

    # retrieve data
    data = json.loads(request_until_succeed(url))

    return data

def getReactionsForStatus(status_id, access_token):

    # See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37239851 for Reactions parameters
        # Reactions are only accessable at a single-post endpoint

    base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6"
    node = "/%s" % status_id
    reactions = "/?fields=" \
            "reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(like)" \
            ",reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(love)" \
            ",reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(wow)" \
            ",reactions.type(HAHA).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(haha)" \
            ",reactions.type(SAD).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(sad)" \
            ",reactions.type(ANGRY).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(angry)"
    parameters = "&access_token=%s" % access_token
    url = base + node + reactions + parameters

    # retrieve data
    data = json.loads(request_until_succeed(url))

    return data


def processFacebookPageFeedStatus(status, access_token):

    # The status is now a Python dictionary, so for top-level items,
    # we can simply call the key.

    # Additionally, some items may not always exist,
    # so must check for existence first

    status_id = status['id']
    status_message = '' if 'message' not in status.keys() else \
            unicode_normalize(status['message'])
    link_name = '' if 'name' not in status.keys() else \
            unicode_normalize(status['name'])
    status_type = status['type']
    status_link = '' if 'link' not in status.keys() else \
            unicode_normalize(status['link'])
    status_permalink_url = '' if 'permalink_url' not in status.keys() else \
            unicode_normalize(status['permalink_url'])
    status_author = unicode_normalize(status['from']['name'])

    # Time needs special care since a) it's in UTC and
    # b) it's not easy to use in statistical programs.

    status_published = datetime.datetime.strptime(\
            status['created_time'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000')
    status_published = status_published + datetime.timedelta(hours=-5) # EST
    # best time format for spreadsheet programs:
    status_published = status_published.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    # Nested items require chaining dictionary keys.

    num_reactions = 0 if 'reactions' not in status else \
            status['reactions']['summary']['total_count']
    num_comments = 0 if 'comments' not in status else \
            status['comments']['summary']['total_count']
    num_shares = 0 if 'shares' not in status else \
            status['shares']['count']

    # Counts of each reaction separately; good for sentiment
    # Only check for reactions if past date of implementation:
    # http://newsroom.fb.com/news/2016/02/reactions-now-available-globally/

    reactions = getReactionsForStatus(status_id, access_token) \
            if status_published > '2016-02-24 00:00:00' else {}

    num_likes = 0 if 'like' not in reactions else \
            reactions['like']['summary']['total_count']

    # Special case: Set number of Likes to Number of reactions for pre-reaction
    # statuses

    num_likes = num_reactions if status_published < '2016-02-24 00:00:00' else \
            num_likes

    def get_num_total_reactions(reaction_type, reactions):
        if reaction_type not in reactions:
            return 0
        else:
            return reactions[reaction_type]['summary']['total_count']

    num_loves = get_num_total_reactions('love', reactions)
    num_wows = get_num_total_reactions('wow', reactions)
    num_hahas = get_num_total_reactions('haha', reactions)
    num_sads = get_num_total_reactions('sad', reactions)
    num_angrys = get_num_total_reactions('angry', reactions)

    # return a tuple of all processed data

    return (status_id, status_message, status_author, link_name, status_type, 
            status_link, status_permalink_url, status_published, num_reactions, num_comments, 
            num_shares,  num_likes, num_loves, num_wows, num_hahas, num_sads, 
            num_angrys)

def scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(group_id, access_token):
    with open('%s_facebook_statuses.csv' % group_id, 'w') as file:
        w = csv.writer(file)
        w.writerow(["status_id", "status_message", "status_author", 
            "link_name", "status_type", "status_link","permalink_url",
            "status_published", "num_reactions", "num_comments", 
            "num_shares", "num_likes", "num_loves", "num_wows", 
            "num_hahas", "num_sads", "num_angrys"])

        has_next_page = True
        num_processed = 0   # keep a count on how many we've processed
        scrape_starttime = datetime.datetime.now()

        print ("Scraping %s Facebook Page: %s\n" % \
                (group_id, scrape_starttime))

        statuses = getFacebookPageFeedData(group_id, access_token, 100)

        while has_next_page:
            for status in statuses['data']:

                # Ensure it is a status with the expected metadata
                if 'reactions' in status:            
                    w.writerow(processFacebookPageFeedStatus(status, \
                                                            access_token))

                # output progress occasionally to make sure code is not
                # stalling
                num_processed += 1
                if num_processed % 100 == 0:
                    print ("%s Statuses Processed: %s" % (num_processed, 
                            datetime.datetime.now()))

            # if there is no next page, we're done.
            if 'paging' in statuses.keys():
                statuses = json.loads(request_until_succeed(\
                        statuses['paging']['next']))
            else:
                has_next_page = False


        print ("\nDone!\n%s Statuses Processed in %s" % \
                (num_processed, datetime.datetime.now() - scrape_starttime))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(group_id, access_token)
```

Error logs:

> > HTTP Error 403: Forbidden Traceback (most recent call last):   File "scrape_facebook.py", line 22, in request_until_succeed
> > response = ur.urlopen(req)   File "C:\Users\Usama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py",
> > line 223, in urlopen
> > return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Users\Usama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py",
> > line 532, in open
> > response = meth(req, response)   File "C:\Users\Usama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py",
> > line 642, in http_response
> > 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File "C:\Users\Usama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py",
> > line 570, in error
> > return self._call_chain(*args)   File "C:\Users\Usama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py",
> > line 504, in _call_chain
> > result = func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Usama\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py",
> > line 650, in http_error_default
> > raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "scrape_facebook.py", line
> 198, in 
> scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(group_id, access_token)   File "scrape_facebook.py", line 168, in scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus
> statuses = getFacebookPageFeedData(group_id, access_token, 100)   File "scrape_facebook.py", line 52, in getFacebookPageFeedData
> data = json.loads(request_until_succeed(url))   File "scrape_facebook.py", line 27, in request_until_succeed
> time.sleep(5) KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: Are you sure you get a HTTP `404` error as your title suggests? The `404` error means the page you were looking for was not found.

Comment: Furter more can you please test your API call in Facebook's API Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to make sure that your query is going well on their site and paste the results here. My tip is that you app is not yet reviewed by Facebook, that's why you get this result.

Comment: are you a group mod/admin?

Comment: @webtobesocial yes i am getting HTTP 404 Error : Forbidden
How to test API call on explorer ? I opened the link and clicked on 'Submit' button and it showed me id and name in json format. I tried using App Token as well as User access token , but same error appears. I am unable to understand whats the issue

Comment: @luschn no , i am not the admin

Comment: pretty sure you cannot access the group feed anymore if you are not admin. btw. if you only get "id and name" in an api response, you may want to read about declarative fields in the official docs.

Comment: @luschn since when facebook made changes ? can i see some official documents where they announced the changes they made ? thanks in advance

Comment: they made a LOT of changes in the last few months: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/

Comment: btw, declarative fields are there since years already.

Comment: @luschn whats declarative fields ? I want posts of a public group ? is it possible now ? I was reading an article last week, it said Facebook has opened the groups api, but developer need to go through a verification process first. Still i think only admins of a group can access the posts. 
Please do tell me if you find any way to scrape group posts

Comment: "only admins of a group can access the posts" - correct. scraping is not allowed on facebook.

Comment: about declarative fields, please read the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/archive#v2_4_new_features