# Field Aliases not working with https graph API request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook GraphAPI's [Field Aliases](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/aliasing-fields)  is not supporting to request via https url.

The followoing is an example wher it is not supported:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/theunrealpage?fields=posts.limit(5){picture,full_picture,link,source,reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(like_reactions)}&access_token=531682143674670|c71A8V6qW0jarwsFqUWjMMJYQqo`

When the request is made it gives the following error:

`error: {
message: "(#100) Unknown fields: like_reactions,love_reactions.",
type: "OAuthException",
code: 100,
fbtrace_id: "Dl3pAPrhdHt"
}`

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has stated that the aliasing functionality is not supported for all edges. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/882975555164278/

A workaround has been suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37621973/1611735