# Using Graph API to get reactions count for posts in feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use Facebook's graph API to access every post in a group's feed, along with the number of reactions of each type, for every post.

When I try with just one reaction type, it works fine:

```
[GROUP_ID]/feed/?fields=message,from,created_time,updated_time,reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count)&limit=1
```

However, when I add multiple reaction types, I receive an error.

```
[GROUP_ID]/feed?fields=message,from,created_time,updated_time,reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count),reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(total_count)&limit=1
```

gives me:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Syntax error \"Field reactions specified more than once. This is only possible before version 2.1\" at character 139: message,from,created_time,updated_time,reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count),reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(total_count)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500,
    "fbtrace_id": "GzMCG2dRioK"
  }
}
```

I followed the syntax in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906590/getting-facebook-post-all-reactions-count-in-single-graph-api-request), however it seems to only work when trying to access reactions for a single post, not for every post in a feed. Is the only option to use the API to grab the post ID's for every post in the feed, and then make individual calls on every post?

Comment: Of course that works the same way. It does not matter whether you access individual posts, or get them from the feed edge.

Comment: @CBroe I don't understand your comment, I'm sorry -- are you saying that making a separate API call on each post, instead of using the feed edge, works the same way as using the feed edge? Thanks!

Comment: The feed edge returns post objects, so you can ask for the same fields when requesting data from this edge, as you would do with a single post object.

Comment: @CBroe yes, I understand that, however when I call multiple reactions on an individual post, it works, but when I call it on a post object via the feed edge, it does not work and prints a syntax error.

Comment: Well that's because you now completely ignored what the point of the other question you yourself linked to was ... to query for more than one reaction type in a single request, you need to use _aliases_  ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[GROUP_ID]/feed?fields=message,from,created_time,updated_time  
,reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_love)
,reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_wow)
&limit=1
```

Then you find instead of `reactions` the fields `reactions_love` and `reactions_wow` with your desired data. You can add all types and it is shortened here for a better overview ;)

Comment: I 've tried and it not worked, 
```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Unknown fields: reactions_love,reactions_wow.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "FLGFSxaSbBo"
  }
}

```

Comment: Here is my code: 

            Connection<JsonObject> myFeed = facebookClient.fetchConnection("1540653099566488" + "/feed",
                JsonObject.class,
                Parameter.with("fields", "reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_love)" +
                        ",reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(reactions_wow)")
        );

"1540653099566488" is the group id, this code work find with page_id, but not with group

Comment: Problems occurring for group feed call only not for page feed call, plz help

Comment: It seems that on groups the field aliasing is not working ('as'). Without the as everything's fine, but you can only get one type of reactions and this is not the idea behind this.

Comment: I have to correct my comment. The aliasing is only possible on a post id not on the feed endpoint. Perhaps aliasing on the feed is a RFE. But for now you have to iterate over the ids and request every id with the fields mentioned above.

Comment: I actually wanted it on feed endpoint else if i make request on every post id with those fields then it's too many requests per display which is simply not expected for various reasons.

Comment: I opened a bug on Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1911644599096974/

Comment: Oh yes.I was thinking to create a question but instead your bug i am following. But there you did not mention that it does not work with group_id/feed endpoint too which is appropriate than me/feed call.i added it there.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around the aliasing issue, and still receive what you need, by asking for the following:

```
    insights.metric(post_reactions_by_type_total).period(lifetime)
```

(I found it here: [Getting Facebook Post all Reactions Count in single Graph API request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906590/getting-facebook-post-all-reactions-count-in-single-graph-api-request/37621973#37621973))