# FB Graph API - Tried accessing nonexisting field (reactions) on node type (Photo)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I am working with FB Graph API to get the names of the users who like or react to my post. By using

```
get/version/{post-id}/likes
```

I have been able to get the names and IDs of all likers. Now I also want to get other reactions i.e. HAHA or Love reactions, but when I use `get/version/{post-id}/reactions` I get this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (reactions) on node type (Photo)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Abwl9IBIxglskXT3yivpWUm"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get all reactions or not?
The users will authorize the app so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically after 3 days of wait, I got no answer. So I decided to post an answer myself. What I found in these 3 days is that it is not possible to get all the reactions. Likes and Care are the only data you will get.

If I ever found a way to get it all, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get all the reactions on a post (including Photos) by requesting this endpoint:

```
{user_id}_{post_id}?fields=
reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(love),
reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(wow),
reactions.type(HAHA).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(haha),
reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(like),
reactions.type(ANGRY).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(angry),
reactions.type(SAD).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(sad)
```

(Remove all newlines, I put them in only to make the URL more readable).

This returns

```
{
  "love": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 50
    }
  },
  "wow": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 20
    }
  },
  "haha": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 24
    }
  },
  "like": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 60
    }
  },
  "angry": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 1
    }
  },
  "sad": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 1
    }
  },
  "id": "{user_id}_{post_id}"
}
```

I got this answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37621973/4237080).

It seems that the Facebook API does not support getting reactions on Photos using the shorthand id, but it supports getting reactions using the longhand id, which is `{user_id}_{post_id}`.