# How can I "react" to a Facebook post (Love, Like, Wow, Sad) using Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Before the Facebook reactions are released, I was able to Like a post using the following:

> https://graph.facebook.com/00000000000000/likes?access_token=XXXXXXX&method=post

However, now the new Facebook reactions are here and I was wondering how to "Love" or "Sad" using the graph API request?

I do not want to get the number of reactions. I want to be able to React as in LIKE or LOVE or WOW a post using Facebook Graph API.

I tried the following:

> https://graph.facebook.com/00000000000000/loves?access_token=XXXXXXX&method=post
>   https://graph.facebook.com/00000000000000/love?access_token=XXXXXXX&method=post
>   https://graph.facebook.com/00000000000000/sad?access_token=XXXXXXX&method=post

But it shows an error.. Anybody has the solution for this? Would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Facebook Reactions with Graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606109/getting-facebook-reactions-with-graph-api)

Comment: I don't want to GET the number of reactions. I want to LOVE or WOW a post using the graph API (post method).

Comment: did you able to find any answer ?